# Can you add buttons to a Tree in smartgwt?

Tags: button, tree, smartgwt

Can you add buttons to a Tree in smartgwt ? (such as a delete button to remove a node). I want the button to be inside the tree.

Comment: Are you using TreeGrid of SmartGWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried but in such a case  I would try to use the `TreeGridField` class as you can  have multiple columns nodes with it so you can probably put some button in one of the columns.
( *If it's just for deleting node you can also hooked a contextmenu to your Treegrid...*)